# why Html form mail gives the coordinates of the image button in firefox

Tags: html

I have a html mail form and I was just wondering why I get the coordinates of the submit image button in the body of the message in firefox, is there a way to delete that.

thanks

```
 <form method="post" action="mailto:miles@faithinstyle.co.uk?subject=Password Request enctype="text/plain">
            <input type="image" id="email_button" src="images/buttons/here.png">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<a href="mailto:miles@faithinstyle.co.uk?subject=Password Request">
    <img id="email_button" src="images/buttons/here.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: nice, helped me as well :)

Answer (score 0):

either don't use `input type=image` or just ignore the data.  what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's not a problem,I was just wondering if there was a way to get rid of it.

Comment: an `a` element is certainly a wrong (and laborous) way to submit form.

Comment: Dear somebody, a you sure that form is really needed in this case? :)

Comment: no, i was just assuming that the method was POST for a reason

Comment: it is just author mistake to choose a form with post method, though